# Sending javascript dictionary with array values via ajax through a bookmarklet

Tags: ajax, json, get, bookmarklet

I have data that I want to send through an ajax GET request in following format - 
{'url':['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com']}

Here is the ajax request - $.ajax({type:'GET',url:'http://www.example.com/',processData:false,data:JSON.stringify({'url':['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com']})

And since I am doing this in a bookmarklet it looks like this -

```
<a href="javascript:function iprl5() {  $.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'http://www.example.com/',
processData:false,
data:JSON.stringify({'url':['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com']}),
dataType:'json', 
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(json){$('#confirm').html('<p>Thanks!</p>');},
error: function(){$('#confirm').html('<p>Something went wrong :( please reload</p>');} })}} iprl5(); void(0)">BLAH</a>
```

The problem is that when I hit the bookmarklet browser sends a get request like this -

```
GET http://www.example.com/?{"url":["www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"]}
```

I want to send a json as a string but unable to do so, I also tried encodeURIComponent to encode string but that didn't work either.

Comment: I want it to send this - `http://www.example.com/?url=["www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try: `data: 'url=' + JSON.stringify(['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com']),`